# Can I sequentially call the methods?

Tags: c#, list, methods

I have methods like this:

```
string MethodName1() { ... }
string MethodName2() { ... }
...
string MethodNameN() { ... }
```

and then create a `methodList`.

Consequently I want to call in loop

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

for(int i=0; i < methodList.count; i++)
{
    MyList.Add(methodList[i]);
}
```

It is possible?

Comment: Have you tried? Was that possible?

Comment: Little side note here, it looks like a pretty strong code smell to me. You might want to solve the problem at the source instead, which is your architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store these methods as `List<Func<string>>`:

```
List<Func<string>> methodList = new List<Func<string>>
{
    MethodName1,
    MethodName2,
    ...
};
```

To call them sequentally and obtain results as the `List<string>`:

```
List<string> myList = methodList.ConvertAll(method => method());
```